# How to save the increment version number in file using python?

Tags: python, regex, file-io

I'm trying to save the version of ElasticSearch in a file.

input file:

```
ElasticSearch 5:1:
```

Output file after first time execute

```
ElasticSearch 5:1:0
```

Output file after Second time execute

```
ElasticSearch 5:1:1
ElasticSearch 5:1:0
```

Output file after third time execute

```
ElasticSearch 5:1:2
ElasticSearch 5:1:1
ElasticSearch 5:1:0
```

My code is below

```
import re
reg = r'(?:)$'
with open('elastic.txt', 'r') as fread:
    data = fread.read()
    with open('elastic.txt', 'a') as fwrite:
        fwrite.seek(0,0)
        fwrite.write(re.sub(reg, lambda x: str(int(x.group(0)) + 1), data, 1, re.M))
```

Two issues I am facing seek(0,0) is not functioning properly and regex is not adding

Comment: FYI, `r'(?:)$'` = `'$'`. It matches the end of string position. Why do you want to increment end of string? What is the actual expected result?

Comment: i want to save the version like starting from 0 and keep on increment while executing

Comment: try `with open('elastic.txt', 'w') as fwrite:`. The `a` stands for append, I'm pretty sure you want to overwrite it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use

```
import re
reg = r'\A(.*:)(\d*)$'
with open('elastic.txt', 'r') as fread:
    data = fread.read()
    with open('elastic.txt', 'w') as fwrite:
        fwrite.write(re.sub(reg, lambda x: "{}{}\n{}".format(x.group(1), str(int(x.group(2)) + 1), x.group()) if len(x.group(2)) else "{}0".format(x.group(1)) , data, 1, re.M))
```

**Details**

- `\A(.*:)(\d*)$` - a regex that gets the line at the start of the file if it has `:` and captures the part up to and including `:` into Group 1 and any zero or more digits into Group 2 (at the end of the line)
- `data` is the whole file contents
- `lambda x: "{}{}\n{}".format(x.group(1), str(int(x.group(2)) + 1), x.group()) if len(x.group(2)) else "{}0".format(x.group(1))` replaces with Group 1, incremented Group 2, and a newline + the whole first line *if* the Group 2 contains digits, else, it adds the `0` to the first line without doubling it.

Comment: thanks its working fine. just one query. how you improvise your coding skills  :)

Comment: @Mous If you mean to ask how I learn regex, I just answer regex questions on SO daily. *Visited 1606 days, 1597 consecutive*

Comment: In above expression can you let me know where you are checking the first line. example if my file have 2 lines, let say and second line has to untouched example. elastic.txt  have 2 lines, ElasticSearch 5.1 and Kibana. and Kibana has to print with ElasticSearch everytime. In this situation where I should mention for the lines

Comment: @Mous `(?m)\A(.*:)(\d*)$` matches the first line always as `\A` is start of the string, `.*` can't match a newline and `$` must match the end of the line. If you want to skip a number of leading lines, you need to add `(?:.*\n){x}` after the `\A(`.

Comment: I have checked with \A(.*:)(\d*)$(?:.*\n){x}. Still if any no new line which is part of ElasticSearch 5.1 is not printing. Example if the file have ElasticSearch 5:1:0 and second line is Kibana 1.0 and expected out put has to ElasticSearch 5:1:1 with Kibana 1.0 , ElasticSearch 5:1:2 with Kibana 1.0 , ElasticSearch 5:1:3 with Kibana 1.0. Can you tell where i need to modify the script

Comment: @Mous You still want to modify the first line, why bother? The code above already does. You misunderstood the idea behind `(?:.*\n){x}`: `x` stands for an integer number that is the number of lines to match and it must be after `\A(`, not after `$`. But it is not what you need as all you want to do is modify the first line. Please explain it in more details, probably, by editing the question itself. Right now, my answer answers your question, but you seem to actually need something else.

Answer (score 0):

Extended solution with custom `incr_patch_version` function:

```
import re

regex = r'(?<=:)\d*$'


def incr_patch_version(fname):
    with open(fname, 'r+') as f:
        lines = f.readlines()
        new_line = re.sub(regex, lambda x: str(int(x.group()) + 1 if x.group().isnumeric() else 0), lines[0])
        f.seek(0)
        f.write(new_line) if lines[0].strip().endswith(':') else f.writelines([new_line, *lines])


fname = 'elastic.txt'

incr_patch_version(fname)
incr_patch_version(fname)
incr_patch_version(fname)
incr_patch_version(fname)
```

The final `elastic.txt` contents:

```
ElasticSearch 5:1:3
ElasticSearch 5:1:2
ElasticSearch 5:1:1
ElasticSearch 5:1:0
```

Comment: In above expression can you let me know where you are checking the first line. example if my file have 2 lines, let say and second line has to untouched example. elastic.txt have 2 lines, ElasticSearch 5.1 and Kibana. and Kibana has to print with ElasticSearch everytime. In this situation where I should mention for the lines , is the below code works?
f.write(new_line + lines[1:] ) if lines[0].strip().endswith(':') else f.writelines([new_line, *lines])

Comment: @Mous, you've declared your input file as that of line `ElasticSearch 5:1:`. So the 1st line is expected to be with "empty" patch number `: `

Comment: if the file have ElasticSearch 5:1:0  and second line is Kibana 1.0 and expected out put has to  ElasticSearch 5:1:1 with Kibana 1.0 , ElasticSearch 5:1:2 with Kibana 1.0 , ElasticSearch 5:1:3 with Kibana 1.0. What is the expression I need to write.

Comment: @Mous, as you have already accepted one of the answers - I assume that you got a solution already as it shown clearly by your decision.

Comment: yep its working fine. But in case of multiple lines which is part of first line, I need to pass only first line and remain lines  untouched. if you have an idea pass in comment otherwise thank you somuch for you time :)

Comment: @Mous, 1) having multiple lines as the 1st line contradicts to the initial condition; 2) you've already accepted another answer, that's a direct conflict of interests